# What will happen when memory is allocated using new for non class pointer

Tags: c++

What will happen when memory is allocated using new for non class pointers?

Example

```
typedef struct {
   int emp_data;
}ST_EMP_DATA;

main()
{
  ST_EMP_DATA *pEmpData = NULL;
  pEmpData = new ST_EMP_DATA;

  // Do some operation using pEmpData 

 delete pEmpData;

}
```

Could someone explain what will happen to the new and delete operators called for structure pointer above?

Comment: A `struct` is actually considered a class in C++, so nothing different.

Comment: In C++ a struct is a class, just with a different default access of `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: So do you have any sample where that actually makes a difference?

Comment: OMG `new int` mind blown?

Comment: For people down/close voting - I personally think this is a fine question for a novice.  I think it's reasonable for someone who is new to the language to believe that C++ might treat `struct` different from `class` or from built-ins (in fact `struct` is different than `class`, just not in a particularly profound way). For example, structs in .NET have significant differences than classes. And while I'd guess there's probably a dupe among the thousands of SO C++ questions, it's not a question I've noticed before that I can remember.

Comment: @KerrekSB: This is not my code. I have seen the usage of code in some places. I searched online and couldn't find much info about this. Hence wrote a sample code to make the question clear

Answer (score 1):

Usability of `new` and `delete` is in no way confined to `class`es. It may be utilized to allocate memory for **every type of data**. The `new` keyword is followed by an **arbitrary** type.

Your example will work just fine. You use `new` and `delete` properly and don't leak any memory and that's what it's all about.